# Output different lines when comparing two files

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, diff

I have two text files with the same number of newline terminated strings. The lines in the two files correspond to each other. The lines in each file individually might be repeated.

I would like to quickly identify which two lines differ and output either from the first file or from the second one.

File A:

```
this is a string
this is another string
empty string
```

File B:

```
this is A string
this is another string
Empty string
```

From perspective of file A, I would like to output first and third lines since they are different than in file B. Similarly for file B, I would output first and third lines of this files.

My standard approach to comparing files was to sort the two files and then use the `comm` binary but sorting would destroy the correspondence between the two files. I also tried to get this done with `diff` but it looks to be designed for a different task.

It would also be ok to output the two differing lines from both files with a tab separation.

Comment: Is every line in File A uniqe and is every line in File B uniqe?

Comment: @Cyrus No, the lines are not unique. The only information is that the two same line number strings are corresponding. For example the line 10 from file A and the line 10 from file B are comparable.

Comment: File A contains multiple times the same lines?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, it can happen that exactly the same line appears in file A (as in file B).

Comment: Please forget file B for one second. Are there lines in file A with appear multiple times (ony in file A)?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, the lines in file A can appear multiple times.

Comment: Okay, what a pity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the comparison from the perspective of `fileA`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next;} $0!=a[FNR]' fileB fileA
this is a string
empty string
```

This approach reads the whole of `fileB` into memory.  Thus, if your files are huge (too big for memory), you should choose another approach.

Similarly, to obtain the output from the perspective of `fileB`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next;} $0!=a[FNR]' fileA fileB
this is A string
Empty string
```

#### More Memory Efficient Approach

This approach only reads in two lines at a time and thus is more memory efficient.  From the perspective of `FileA`:

```
$ awk '{a=$0;getline <"fileA";} $0!=a' fileB
this is a string
empty string
```

From the perspective of `fileB`:

```
$ awk '{a=$0;getline <"fileB";} $0!=a' fileA
this is A string
Empty string
```

Comment: Can this be improved by actually storing ones and zeros in the "a" array instead of strings? It could be more memory efficient.

Comment: @xeon I just added a memory-efficient approach.